# How to create input[type=image] in input[type=text] in html

Tags: html, css, web

I want to get textfield like apple' textbox:

[image: Apple' Text Field]

But i can create only this:

[image: my textbox]

**My code:**

```css
.my-textfield, .my-textfield:focus {
  width: 253px;
  height: 27px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  padding-left: 4.5px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #CECDD2;
}
.ico-close:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <input class="my-textfield">
  <input class="ico-close" type="image" src="error.png">
</form>
```

So, can i move it into textfield? (I don't need search icon on the left corner)

Comment: where is ur code? use position: absolute;

Comment: ouch, i forgot to add code, sorry. Wait

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My case

```css
.applelike {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.applelike > input[type=text] {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 32px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height: 32px;
  padding: 0 32px;
  display: block;
}
.applelike span#zoom {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 32px;
  color: #000;
}
.applelike span#close {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 6px;
  top: 6px;
  width: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: lightgray;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 32px;
}
```

```html
<div class="applelike">
  <span id="zoom">&#128269;</span>
  <input type="text">
  <span id="close">&#10006;</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to do "close" button clickable?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say a good aproach is to try using the :after pseudo element to generate an "content"... to do this:

```
.my-textfield, .my-textfield:focus {
  width: 253px;
  position: relative; /*this makes it targetable by the :after element position*/
  height: 27px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  padding-left: 4.5px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #CECDD2;
}
.my-textfield {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-image: url('USE AN IMAGE THAT YOU WANT HERE');
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 5px;
}
```

it should look something like this... this creates for every element an after element that just fits inside it's parent... for the rest, adjust size, positioning and the image!

good luck!

Comment: Thanks, but... This is don't work. And may be asked wrong, but i wanted to get image in textfield. If user click this image - textfield will clear text; Of course i can clear text, but i don't understand how to get this button. I didn't found anything information like "How to get image button in textfield html css". But i'd found this input with image type. This type is clickable and i can add action. But how to add this button (image type="button", idk how to call that :) ) into textfield and add to it action if i can't add "clear" button. I know about input type submit, but no...